# Retrieve JSON based on another JSON in Angular Service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am quite new to Angular and I'm not sure how to accomplish what seems to be a simple task. I want to retrieve a JSON file using $http.get, and then use items from that array to create a URL to retrieve more JSON files to display. I know that my code is incorrect, but I think it helps to show what I am trying to accomplish.

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http) {

  var topStor = $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty');

  var stor = $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' 
    + topStor[0] + '.json?print=pretty');

  return stor

  .success(function(data) {
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are async by default. Angular uses a promise pattern to handle the asynchronous response from [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
var topStor = $http.get(...); // topStor is now the promise and not the value
```

The `success` method will be called on the returned promise when the request is successful. So to get the array from the original request:

```
$http.get(URL).success(function(data, status) {
  // data is the array from the response
});
```

A nested request can then be made from the data received from the original request.

```
$http.get(URL).success(function(data, status) {
  $http.get(UTL + data[0]).success(function(innerData, innerStatus) {
    // celebrate with innerData
  }).error(function(errData, errStatus) {});
}).error(function(errData, errStatus) {});
```

Note: `success` and `error` are special methods added to the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service that Angular uses.

> Since the returned value of calling the $http function is a promise, you can also use the then method to register callbacks, and these callbacks will receive a single argument – an object representing the response. See the API signature and type info below for more details.
>
> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http) {

  var topStor = $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty');
  return topStor
     .success(function(){
          var stor = $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' 
    + topStor[0] + '.json?print=pretty');

        return stor

         .success(function(data) {
            return data;
         })
         .error(function(err) {
            return err;
         });
      })
      .error(function(){

      });  
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q to your advantage here.  Return a promise that resolves with the data you're after:

```
    app.factory('posts', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

      function getStory() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $http.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' 
            + data[0] + '.json?print=pretty')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              deferred.reject('There was a problem getting the story');
            });
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject('There was a problem getting the top stories');
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }

      return {
        getStory: getStory
      }
    }]);
```